# Span tag inside the div tag is not appearing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have to create a `span` inside the `div` tag in CKEditor on `onclick` event of dialog window. I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
link = editor.document.createElement( 'div' );
this.commitContent( data );
link.setAttribute('itemscope','');
link.setAttribute( 'itemtype', 'http://schema.org/Person' );
link.setAttribute( 'id', 'person' );
link1 = editor.document.createElement( 'span' );
document.getElementById("person").appendChild(link1);
link1.setAttribute( 'itemprop', data.prop );
```

Comment: span by default is not `display: block` which means it would not take up the available space, but would limit to wrapping the inner content. So, you need to specify `display: block` in order for it to show up.

Comment: @karthikr , thanks for your response, but its not working . gives this error:TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

Comment: @karthikr ,link1.setStyle( 'display', 'block' );

Comment: @DJDavid98, ya may be because I am creating element haing that id just a line before calling appendChild() method.see the code in question

Answer (score 0):

You completely mixed up native DOM API with [CKEditor's API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element). It's even hard to guess what you had in mind writing that code, but I hope that this will help you a little:

```
var link = editor.document.createElement( 'div' );
this.commitContent( data );
link.setAttributes( {
    itemscope: '',
    itemtype: 'http://schema.org/Person',
    id: 'person'
} );
// Now you need to append link somewhere...
editor.editable().append( link );

var link1 = editor.document.createElement( 'span' );
link1.appendTo( link );
link1.setAttribute( 'itemprop', data.prop );
```

Comment: that gives me this error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'editable'

Comment: So you've got something else broken. Editor has method `editable`. See [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable). PS. Ok, I got it - you're using CKEditor 3. Editable was introduced in CKEditor 4. So replace `editor.editable()` with `editor.document.getBody()`. Or better - upgrade CKEditor.